# Redundant Condition for Subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm studying Raleigh's Abstract Algebra, and I came across this problem (5.44):

> Find the flaw in the following argument:
>
> "Condition 2 of Theorem 5.14 is redundant, since it can be derived
>   from 1 and 3, for let $a \in H$. Then $a^{-1} \in H$ by 3, and by 1, $aa^{-1} = e$ is an element of H, proving 2."

Here is the theorem that the problem is referring to:

> **Theorem 5.14** A subset $H$ of a group $G$ is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if
>
> 1. $H$ is closed under the binary operation of $G$
> 2. The identity element $e$ of $G$ is in $H$
> 3. For all $a \in H$ it is true that $a^{-1} \in H$ also.

The thing is, I don't see what's wrong with the argument. Can anyone point out the subtlety that I'm missing here?

Comment: subgroups have to be nonempty

Comment: Ah! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

If $H$ is *empty set*, you can't pick an arbitrary element in $H$. Also $H$ does not contain identity since it is an empty set.

Comment: Ah, thanks so much! I hadn't thought to look at something so basic.